# Roslyn: Checking for an uninitialized local variable

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, code-analysis

Using Roslyn, how do I check if a C# variable is uninitialized? e.g. Suppose I have the following code:

```
void M()
{
    CancellationToken l1;
    N();
}
```

and I have the `ILocalSymbol` corresponding to `l1`. How do I check whether this variable is initialized at a particular position in the syntax tree, for example the index in the text corresponding to `N();`?

**edit:** It would be helpful if the approach extended to parameter symbols as well, e.g.

```
void M(out CancellationToken p1)
{
    N(); // How do I tell p1 is uninitialized here?
}
```

**edit:** I've tried the data flow analysis API per the advice of some people on the Roslyn team: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23688. However, it's not working. I've tried `!analysis.DataFlowsIn.Contains(symbol)` as well as `!analysis.AlwaysAssigned.Contains(symbol)` (where `analysis` is a `DataFlowAnalysis` object) but they both give false negatives, saying the variable is uninitialized when it isn't.

Comment: What do you mean *how do you check*?  I mean I can look at that and tell you `l1`is uninitialized.  Or run the compiler and see if it throws en error...?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I am asking about Roslyn, a C# static analysis tool.

Comment: Did you try the data flow analysis API? Did you have problems with it? If so, ask a more specific question about the API.  If not, try the data flow analysis API and see how you like it.

Comment: @EricLippert See my updated post. Would you be able to help me since you have expertise with Roslyn?

Comment: If the API is giving false negatives and you're using it correctly then that's a bug in the implementation; take it up with the Roslyn team. I haven't worked there in over five years.